# Angular 2 architecture for server-side communication

Tags: angularjs, angular

Learning Angular 2. What would a recommended file structure for having components communicating with a server?

So a feature, say a todo feature. It may have a main `todo-component`, a `todo-list-component`, a `todo-item-component`, `new-todo-component` and a `todo-service` (and probably more).

Then there is another feature, say a personal activity timeline, which takes several source (including new and finished todos) and present it to the user. Say it may have the same type of files, but so different that we could not combine them into generic ones: a main `timeline-component`, a `timeline-list-component`, a `timeline-item-component` and a `timeline-service`.

Then we want for both the todo and the timeline features to communicate with the server. Since they both access partly the same data, perhaps a good idea would to have a `backend-service` to take care of the server communication for both features.

But how should the components get the data it's need? Should the todo components ask the todo-service which in turn asks the `backend-service` (and similar for the timeline components)? Or should the components better use the backend-service directly, so for example the todo components would use `backend-service` for backend stuff and `todo-service` and for other things that is naturally to put in a service? Since this is async and there are observables involved (which in the first case would need to be sent over multiple "steps" somehow), perhaps the latter is a simpler/cleaner approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the *Component* should use a proper *Service* to pipe itself into the data flow with *Observables*.
If we look for instance at the [Chat application example](https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat) we can see that each *Service* has a clear responsibility for the data management.
I wouldn't allow a *Component* to access a generic **Http** service as it would need to host too much logic to communicate with the server: the **component doesn't care about the data source**, just shows the data.